# Recurrence - using power series

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, recurrence-relations, power-series, recursive-algorithms

Could you help me in solving this recursion( a closed form ) using power series

$\mu(n)=\mu(n−1)k_0+(n−1)\mu(n−2) k_1 \tag 1$,

where $k_0,k_1$ are constants $\mu(0)=3,\mu(1)=5$

HINT: **We can think about a substitution such that it will be converted to a solvable non varying coefficient case.. Just thinking..**

NB :: Avoid any methods where $k_i$s come as denominator in any steps. We are looking for a higher dimension like matrices, compatible solution. So a method based on series will be ideal for upward compatibility(**Avoid ODE methods**,Issue is upward compatibility with matrices. All matrices are not commutative. So it will be an issue when solving ODE.). Keep the positions of $k_i$ as it is in the question(by seeing the upward compatibility for matrices). A solution which satisfies the constraints in the question for non matrices can be easily transformed to matrices.. Thanks

Comment: do you need a closed-form expression for $\mu(n)$?

Comment: Yes.. A closed form is ideal

Comment: Consider that $\mu(n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ and just replace in the equation and you'll find the $a_n$ that will gives you the solution.

Comment: Would you elaborate bit Please..I guess I tried that already

Comment: $\mu$ parameter is bit confusing with summation index.. Please make it correct

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mu(n) x^n$, the recursion corresponds to a differential equation for $g(x)$.  Solve that differential equation with initial conditions $g(0) = 3$, $g'(0) = 5$.

EDIT: Actually that won't work in this case, because the differential equation has a nasty singularity at $0$.

Note that with $\mu(n) = k_0^{n} u(n)$ and $k_1 = c k_0^2 $ the recursion becomes

$$u(n) = u(n-1) + c (n-1) u(n-2),\ n \ge 2$$

Rather than an ordinary generating function, consider an exponential generating function

$$G(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty u(n) z^n/n!$$

Using Maple's gfun package, I find that two linearly independent egf's satifying this recurrence are

$$G_1(z) = \exp((cz+1)^2/(2c)),\ G_2(z) = \text{erf}((cz+1)/\sqrt{2c}) \exp((cz+1)^2/(2c))$$

The appropriate linear combination of these will satisfy your initial conditions.

Comment: I know that solution. That is why specially mentioned only using Power series . Issue is upward compatibility with matrices. All matrices are not commutative. So it will be an issue when solving ODE.. Thanks sir

Comment: If you have a particular matrix recursion in mind, why not ask about that directly rather than trying to adapt the solution to one problem to a different problem?

Comment: It is easy that people may get confused with matrix calculus. I had experience here in the same regard. So I posted a recursion with constraints so that,it can be upgraded easily to matrix. And may invite more thoughts of the solution from people who are not familiar with matrix calculus.  Thanks